# Floating IMG resize percentage

Tags: css, image-resizing

I'm trying to resize an img proportionally with the container. The IMG floats left and there is a paragraph wrapping around it.

HTML:

```
<div>
<img src="picture.png">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vestibulum venenatis      libero, eu egestas elit laoreet nec. Donec in nunc dictum nunc luctus eleifend sagittis id augue.</p>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 80%;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

​The image gets resized only when the left div border hits the image and the paragraph is completely bellow the img. I want to resize the img as soon as the div resizes. I know I can put the img in a wrapper div and give it a percentage width, but I'd like a cleaner solution, if it's possible.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/989uX/

Comment: `IMG` itself can use percentage width. Can you demonstrate what exactly you want with a wrapper `DIV`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'max-width' CSS property sets the maximum content width of the IMG element. In other words, this element is never wider even if you set a bigger width.
If you want to re-size the element you should use the 'width' property instead of 'max-width'. This property accepts also percentage values (as Passerby mentioned above). Note that percentage values of the element refer to the width of the containing block.